# setInterval works but delayed one cycle

Tags: javascript, setinterval

my goal is to display a word from the array every four seconds unless the user types the word correctly in less than four seconds in which case the interval is cleared and restarted. when i click start four seconds pass before the word is displayed. i want it to show immediatly and every four seconds thereafter unless the user types the correct word before four seconds in which case the interval is cleared and restarted and in that case there is a four second delay before the next word is shown. Why is it that the interval runs through the count once before performing the action. How can i fix this? I am not familiar with jquery so please some advice in js`

```js
startBtn.addEventListener('click', startGame);
answerBox.addEventListener('keyup', checkWord);


function startGame() {
    //showWord();
    gameTimer = setInterval(gameTime, 1000);
    timedWordDisplay = setInterval(showWord, 4000);
    }



function checkWord() {
    let currentWordLen = answerBox.value.length;
    if (wordDisplayBox.innerHTML === answerBox.value) {
        clearInterval(timedWordDisplay);
        numWordsRight++;
        numGoodWordsField.innerHTML = numWordsRight;
        answerBox.value = '';
        answerBox.focus();
        wordDisplayBox.innerHTML = '';
        timedWordDisplay = setInterval(showWord, 4000);
    } else if (answerBox.value === currentWord.substring(0, currentWordLen)) {
             answerBox.style.borderColor = 'green';
    } else {
      answerBox.style.borderColor = 'red';
    }
    
        
    
}

/* function checkWord() {
    let currentWordLen = answerBox.value.length;
    if (wordDisplayBox.innerHTML === answerBox.value) {
        clearInterval(showWord);
        goodScore++;
        numGoodWordsField.innerHTML = goodScore;
        answerBox.value = '';
        answerBox.focus();
        setInterval(showWord,4000);
    } else if (answerBox.value === currentWord.substring(0,currentWordLen)) {
      answerBox.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    } else {
      answerBox.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
    
}
*/

function showWord() {
    answerBox.focus();
    console.log('show word func start');
    console.log('seconds between ' + time);
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*wordsLevelOne.length);
        console.log('random number is:' + randomNum);
    currentWord = wordsLevelOne[randomNum];
    console.log('curentWord is ' + currentWord);
    wordDisplayBox.innerHTML = currentWord;
    //setInterval(wordTime, 1000);
    //showWord();
}
```

Comment: Call `showWord()` before setting the interval.

Comment: thank you Mark. it works now on the correct timing. Why is it that the setInterval seems to wait one period of time (4000ms in my case)to perform the function called inside it?

Comment: Because setInterval is actually a recursive setTimeout (at least in specs, some implementations make it a bit more complex with a drift-corrected-recursive-setTimeout, but I digress).

Answer (score -1):

You can use **setTimeout** and **clearTimeout** to reset

```
var tmr;
function startTimer() {
    tmr = setTimeout(showWord, 4000);
}

function stopTimer() {
    if(tmr) {
        clearTimeout(tmr);
    }
}
```